# OAuth2RestTemplate and handling of expired tokens

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, bearer-token, oauth2resttemplate

We have been using Spring Oauth2 rest template and has been working well. 
Can someone please clarify on what the recommendations are for handling expired bearer tokens.
The OAuth 2 spec states that the consumer should return 401 with error = invalid_token.

Is it expected that the Oauth2RestTemplate detect the invalid_token response and then request a fresh token from the auth server? Or should it be smart to know that the token is going to expire and request a new token beforehand?

Can some one kindly recommend the best practice? I think it is doing the former correctly, but wanted to know if there is any value in doing the latter.